# Memory exhausted error for json_parse with PHP

Tags: php, memory, scripting, json

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$FILE="giant-data-barf.txt";

$fp = fopen($FILE,'r');

//read everything into data
$data = fread($fp, filesize($FILE));
fclose($fp);

$data_arr = json_decode($data);
var_dump($data_arr);
?>
```

The file giant-data-barf.txt is, as its name suggests, a huge file(it's 5.4mb right now, but it could go up to several GB)

When I execute this script, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in ........./data.php on line 12
```

I looked at possible solutions, and saw this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

and my question is, is there a limit to how big I should set my memory? Or is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: This may not be a job PHP is perfectly suitable for. Can you use command line tools?

Comment: flat file storage of a file that size is going to cause you many problems. Use sqlite or mysql. if the file contains just one variable that has been json encoded and it is that huge, it's unlikely you'll be able to solve this. json isn't meant for such large files. Use a database, or store it in CSV, or store each row in json instead of the entire thing

Comment: The only problem is, someone is exporting me the entire DB in JSON format...

Comment: How about JSON streaming parser?
https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**THIS IS A VERY BAD IDEA**, that said, you'll need to set

```
ini_set('memory_limit',filesize($FILE) + SOME_OVERHEAD_AMOUNT);
```

because you're reading the entire thing into memory. You may very well have to set the memory limit to *two* times the size of the file since you *also* want to `JSON_DECODE`

**NOTE THAT ON A WEB SERVER THIS WILL CONSUME MASSIVE AMOUNTS OF MEMORY AND YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS IF THE FILE WILL BE MANY GIGABYTES AS YOU SAID!!!!**

Is it really a *giant* JSON blob? You should look at converting this to a database or other format which you can use random or row access with *before* parsing with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I've given all my servers a `memory_limit` of 100M... didn't run into trouble yet.

I would consider splitting up that file somehow, or get rid of it and use a database

Comment: is there a way to import a JSON file into a DB?

Comment: @TonyStark using a go-between custom written app to take that file and convert it to something MySQL understands, sure. To do it using current tools? I doubt it. There are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: dunnow... never did this before :/

Comment: And I suggest you never do! See my answer ;-)

Comment: And what is the way to load a large json file/object into a mysql database? I mean json_decode will throw an Out of memory message!